# Docker NGINX sub_filter not working for HTML-form-item "action" in response

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, httpresponse, nginx-reverse-proxy

We just encountered a problem in which we cannot get our nginx server to rewrite the response content hes getting.

```
location "^/path(.*)$" {   
    resolver 8.8.8.8;  
    set $proxy_target_host "Correct Url is here";
    proxy_set_header Host $proxy_target_host;
    proxy_pass "Correct Url is here";

    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter_types *;
    sub_filter "https://Correct Url is here too/" "/";
}
```

We had an equivalent part in which we used sub_filters. It worked there. Except the sub_filter the whole location is working fine.
The part we want to rewrite equals the first string we define in the sub_filter part. Our NGINX-Dockerimage (docker-compose.yaml) also implements the http_sub_module.

Are there any special cases in which the module wont work? I think im kinda lacking some deeper knowledge since im new to Nginx.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using `sub_filter` with form action attributes. I switched to using `subs_filter` instead and now it works. You can find the information on nginx Substitutions module [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/substitutions). The only slight drawback is that it does not ship with nginx so you will need to re-compile nginx with a --add-module flag, but the instructions are included in the link.